# map function is not callable in lambda function

Tags: python, pyspark, mapreduce

I am looking to do a reduce on a previously created list. In output the result puts me "'map' object is not callable" or by removing the list it returns "<map object at 0x7fc398d98670>"

I don't see where the error comes from.

```
import pyspark  
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType, StringType   
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType    
from itertools import groupby

words = data_df.select('name_annonceur').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
mapping = map((lambda x : (x, 1)), words)

sorted_mapping = sorted(mapping)
grouper = groupby(sorted_mapping, lambda p:p[0])

reduce = map(lambda l: (l[0], reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda p:p[1], l[1]))), grouper)
```

[the code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3Yxy.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask]. A [mcve] would help.

Answer (score 0):

### MRE

Let's start by making a minimal reproducible example. The bug is not at all related to pyspark, it hits when applying Python functions to a simple data structure created as a result of a pyspark query. Deleting all the database-related stuff and inserting some hardcoded example data (of the same structure as visible in your screenshot) makes the bug easier to reproduce for other people (without having to set up a database and install pyspark):

```
from itertools import groupby

# hardcoded example data based on what we can see in the screenshot you posted
words = ['White Bug Entertainment', 'White Bug Entertainment', 'Blaststream', 'Teamtap', 'Teamtap']

mapping = map((lambda x : (x, 1)), words)
sorted_mapping = sorted(mapping)
grouper = groupby(sorted_mapping, lambda p:p[0])
reduce = map(lambda l: (l[0], reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda p:p[1], l[1]))), grouper)

print(list(reduce))
```

### Fixing it

The code works fine in Python 2.7, printing

```
[('Blaststream', 1), ('Teamtap', 2), ('White Bug Entertainment', 2)]
```

but crashes in Python 3 with the error message you reported.

```
TypeError: 'map' object is not callable
```

It's suspicious that the code calls a function called `reduce` and assigns the result to a variable of the same name. If we change name of the variable `reduce` e.g. to `result`

```
# ...
result = map(lambda l: (l[0], reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda p:p[1], l[1]))), grouper)
print(list(result))
```

Python 3 starts throwing a new exception:

```
NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined
```

That's because in Python 3 `reduce` is never more a built-in function (like it was in Python 2), but lives in the `functools` module. Add the missing import statement

```
from functools import reduce
```

and now the code works in Python 3, too.

### What was happening in your code

In Python 3 the `map` function does not do the mapping work immediately (as it did in Python 2), but returns an iterator object which will eventually do the work later, if asked for it. The iterator is assigned to the variable `reduce`.
When you call `list(result)`, the mapping finally starts to happen, the lambda is called and calls `reduce`, but at that point of time `reduce` is a variable holding the iterator, which is not callable, and an exception is thrown.